# how to resolve this error in formula field "Error: Field TZoffset does not exist. Check spelling."

Tags: administration

i am trying to use "TZoffset" in formula field but i am receving this error "Error: Field TZoffset does not exist. Check spelling." can someone help me.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! *Firstly*, please do not post the same question multiple times - and especially do not post a question [as an answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/378439/81648). *Secondly*, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/378445/edit) this question to add your formula (preferably with three backticks (```) above and below your formula to format it as code to make it more readable.)

Answer (score 1):

This is limitation from salesforce and you cannot use TZoffset in formulas.  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdizHUAR/make-tzoffset-a-standard-user-field-accessible-in-formulas).

Thanks

Comment: To Covert "Start Time" field format in "Chat Transcript" Object from hh:mm to hh:mm:ss is there any solution. please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think we can change the format, this is something which is automatically generated when the chat is [initiated](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317079&type=1)